# Javascript time function values

Tags: javascript

I know this question may sound too elementary but at the moment am just desperate.

Am trying to get time value in the following format below via **Javascript**.
In php I can just do

```
<?php

echo $hm=time();

?>
```

Here is the result: **1544862128**

Now I want to implement that using Javascript but it gives me 12 digit instead of 10 digit

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

//var d = new Date();
var t = d.getTime();

//alert(d);
alert(t);

</script>

</head>
<body>
Alert Time values
</body></html>
```

Comment: I get 13 digits, not 12. `1 544 862 645 756` (ms included)

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://clivewalkden.co.uk/blog/jquery/php-time-equivalent-for-javascript.php) will help. Tested and seems to give 10 digits